# Circular / Round Stair Case

Tags: stairs

I'm building this circular staircase in Ontario Canada in a residential home. And am looking for some advice to make sure I'm meeting code. There seem to be lots of parameters when it comes to requirements.

Stringers will be glued and laminated once rough framed.

**Do these steps meet code?**

I've attached screenshots of my CAD designs. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be sure to check with local codes. Btw, we did one in a doctors house several years ago and the way we “sold” it to him was we told him it looked like DNA double helix. He love it.

Answer (score 1):

The code requires certain minimum and maximum dimensions for spiral stairs.

The Code defines the “walk line” as a distance 12” from the narrowest portion of the stair AND the tread must be a minimum of  7 1/2” wide. (See ICC R311.7.9.1)

The riser shall be uniform in height and a maximum of 9 1/2”.

The width of the stair shall be a minimum of 26” wide below the handrails. That is to say, the handrails cannot protrude into the 26”, but you can make the stairs wider and have the handrails protrude into that space. (See ICC R311.7.9)

Also, there shall be a minimum of 6’-6” headroom.

Handrails shall be not less than 30” above the nosing of the tread and not more than 38”. (See ICC R311.7.7.1)

Comment: There's a few subtleties if you're conforming to OBC. There's a cheat sheet here: http://ottawavalleyhandrailing.ca/resources-ideas/stair-measurements/  (For example, riser height is 7-7/8" or less.) Ultimately, you need to check these plans with your permits people before you build.